# How to seed sqlite3 with Rails seed.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord

To whom it may concern,

Basic Rails app. Created a model called "Images" via `rails g model images url:string`

Put some jpg's in the Public folder and set up seed.rb file like this:

```
    images = Image.create([
        { url: "/public/images/01.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/02.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/03.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/04.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/05.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/06.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/07.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/08.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/09.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/10.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/11.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/12.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/13.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/14.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/15.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/16.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/17.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/18.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/19.jpg"},
        { url: "/public/images/20.jpg"}
    ])
```

Ran `rake db:setup`, `rake db:seed`, and `rake db:migrate` to try to seed the sqlite3 data base.

I go into `db/development.sqlite3` and run `.databases` and find nothing. I run `.tables` and find nothing.

```
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main
```

Why did this not seed the database?

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: What is the output of your log ?

Comment: You wrote that you "Ran rake db:setup, rake db:seed, and rake db:migrate to try to seed the sqlite3 data base." You have to run rake db:migrate *before* you try to seed the database, otherwise, you're trying to seed non-existent tables with data. Try rake db:setup db:migrate db:seed and then see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a couple of issues working against you at this point.

You're trying to create a model with the command:

```
rails g model images url:string
```

By convention, you should be both capitalizing and using the singular form of the model name like so:

```
rails g model Image url:string
```

You wrote that you "Ran `rake db:setup`, `rake db:seed`, and `rake db:migrate` to try to seed the sqlite3 data base." You have to run `rake db:migrate` before you try to seed the database, otherwise, you're trying to seed non-existent tables with data. Try `rake db:setup db:migrate db:seed` and then see what happens.